# how to send workflow emails in a specific time zone in sharepoint

Tags: workflow, email, timezone

We have a situation where the requests created in SharePoint list, go for approval to "Approvers". Now some approvers are in US and some in UK.

Can we do something to send emails during a certain time to people in UK and then during US hours to a US contact.

Thanks for your response in advance.